# Can I set Function Returns Table output to inherit the datatype based on Return Query?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using a function in PostgreSQL with a return table output set to fixed number of columns with a query inside. In a typical scenario I need to specify what datatype will be for the columns which is the output.

However, Can I instead have the columns inherit the datatype of the select query inside function by using %type or something?

Comment: No, not possible. If the function returns rows from a single table, you could use `returns setof tablename` though

Comment: You cannot  inherit the type from the select. But you can 'inherit' the return type from a column definition. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7fb69ee11a86f84ddf1e87bbd5336a7b) fiddle.